# Truecrypt system partition boot loader constantly fails / corrupts

Tags: truecrypt

I hope here is technically skilled people to help me out.

About two weeks ago my TC system partition suddenly refused to boot. Will not accept password. After that used recovery disk. Did not help.

Then restore whole encrypted partition back in place, image was taken 5 years ago. It is 100% clean and working. It worked two boots, then same again: no password accepted.
Then tried recovery disk, this time it worked. But once again, lasted 1-2 boots only.

Then one more time, formatted, wiped the drive, restored back original backup (sector-by-sector) -mode. Lasted couple of boots again, then bang again. This time, recovery disk said: write error 128, when trying to restore original boot loader. Header it will restore successfully.

So how this all can be possible. Restored fully working image, it was not altered in any way in these 5 years. Now it will last two boots. This problem even started without restoring it, current setup was acting same way suddenly.

Machine does not have any hardware changes. I wonder what are the sectors that causes this. Is the drive failing, refusing to write to some sectors? It allows restore the header, but it will not help.
It will not allow to restore boot loader anymore. Only text: Modify drive 0 y/n, then I press "y". Then it stucks for about 2 minutes, then "drive write error 128" or something very similar.

So what is going on? - This has gone beyond me. - Thanks in advance.

And please save me from comments TC is discontinued, should not use, or similar. I don't believe rumors at all, and my system works 100% with it, only this particular HDD fails constantly.

-Alphie, Sweden

Comment: You should be using Veracrypt now. Truecrypt was abandoned years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Sad to say but knowingly using a discontinued software product is asking for trouble. It wasn't simply abandoned but the publishers [actively discourage users from using it](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net). As such, you can't expect there to be a continued network of support - especially since troubleshooting a discontinued product can be unpredictable and nightmarish.

If you're desperate to continue with what you have, you might attempt to find a community of Truecrypters over at the [Opencrypt Project](https://opencryptoaudit.org/), which still unofficially hosts a v7.1 [mirror on Github](https://github.com/AuditProject).

You can certainly try to hold out on Superuser for someone who can work with you. However, given the volume of questions we have on SU, people will be less amenable to putting their time into supporting abandonware - not to mention this particular software's [controversial nature](https://medium.com/asecuritysite-when-bob-met-alice/the-fall-of-truecrypt-and-rise-of-veracrypt-44f910ed5162).